# Rounding lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to create a lambda function that will round a value passed onto it, with an amount of decimal places also specified

I made the following

```
c = lambda x: round(x, dp)
```

where dp was already specified

However, trying to call this gave the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

when I typed

```
c(23.2323332345435)
```

I may be half asleep, but I'm pretty sure that's how a simple lambda function is created, and I can't understand why it won't work.

I tried encasing in parens to no avail

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you used/overrode `round`, that's the only callable in the expression besides the lambda which is OK. Use `print(type(round))` to find out.

Comment: Why are you using a `lambda` in the first place, instead of just writing `def c(x): ...`?

Comment: Also, the function will use the value of the global `dp` when it is *called*, not the value `dp` had when the function was *defined*.

Answer (score 2):

That's what happens if you accidentally override `round`, before or after defining the lambda:

```
>>> c = lambda x: round(x, 5)
>>> c(34.44)
34.44
>>> round=12
>>> c(34.44)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the value of **dp** before defining **lambda** function.
Then only it works.

```
    dp=5
    c=lambda x,dp: round(x,dp)
    print c(56.3453453453432)
```

[image: Here is the screenshot.]

And if you want to define the value of **dp** after defining **lambda** function then you can pass two values to the **lambda** function.

```
    c=lambda x,dp: round(x,dp)
    dp=5
    print c(56.3453453453432,dp)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you shadowed `round`.

```
>>> c = lambda x: round(x)
>>> c(13.4)
13
>>> round = 5
>>> c = lambda x: round(x)
>>> c(13.4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Check your code for anywhere you've assigned an object the name `round`. Once you've found it, replace it with another name. You can read more about shadowing [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#Python).